# How to Update only important Security Packages in redhat 5.6

Tags: rhel, package-management

One of our client has Redhat 5.6 and he is asking to update only the important packages.

But question is how do we know which are the important packages.

Note:: It will be a partial Update not complete update.

Comment: Any update issued by RedHat intended to be part of 5.6 will be important.

Comment: Just tell them that after a detailed analysis "this is the list of important packages, and BTW this other bunch has to be updated for dependencies" (for some semi-random split into important/dependency). _Do_ learn from Dilbert [I might be misattibuting]: "A consultant is somebody who you pay a lot of money to tell you what you knew all along". You can cite me as expert, if you want ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the **yum-security** package which is the "Yum plugin to enable security filters". From the package info:

> This plugin adds the options --security, --cve, --bz and --advisory flags
>   to yum and the list-security and info-security commands.
>   The options make it possible to limit list/upgrade of packages to specific
>   security relevant ones. The commands give you the security information.